# Where to save CONSUMER_SECRET and CONSUMER_KEY for oAuth app

Tags: python, svn, twitter, oauth

I am working on a python program that runs as an svn post-commit hook.  It posts your commit message to Twitter.

It works great, but I just realized something.  My CONSUMER_SECRET and CONSUMER_KEY are right there in the source code.  That's probably a bad thing.

I'm new to python, and I was actually just converting someone else's program to oAuth from basic HTTP auth.  I am using [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) to post to twitter.

So, how can I securely save my consumer oAuth keys so that people cannot view them?

**EDIT**: Is it possible to save my keys somewhere where my app can read them, but users can't?  I want everyone using this hook to be using my app, so on their tweets it says "via MyApp".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep such things in a settings file that you do not commit to your versioning system or code repository in any way. Rather provide a template for the file with documentation on how to populate it with the needed settings (such as their application credentials).

Comment: What he said! Always store your configuration file somewhere on the system that isn't available from the web, but where the application code can still read it!

Comment: When people implement your hook they should have to put their own consumer secret and key in their version, in a manner that you hopefully will have documented by then. As long as YOU are running the python program of course the application credentials have to live in the code.

Comment: Oh, so I should require people to make their own Twitter apps and use their own consumer keys?  I was hoping that they could all use mine, so it would say "via <MyApp>" on their Tweets with a link to the app.

Comment: Right, that is, if the hook has to be run of the same server as the svn instance. You could set up your hook that calls an API that you host, which in turn posts to twitter. But if you plan to ship the code in any way whatsoever I would advice against including your credentials (they could be used for any purpose, any app, outside your control).

Comment: Thanks.  Making my own API sounds like a good idea, lets me learn how to make an API.  I should also probably revoke my current key, because it's in the source code >.<